# Returning 2 Previous Functions After "Click" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

I have written a code that returns reports for parks and reports for streets.  For practice I added an event listener to console log the results after a click.  It works fine when you click the green and blue boxes. It should report the individual reports associated to them and when I click the orange box I want both reports console logged, but everything I have tried keeps returning undefined.  I have put the functions in variables, kept them out of variables, consoled logged the variables as functions.  I can't seem to figure it out. This is what I have.  I have used function constructors before the code listed and also a function to calculate averages.  Some input would be greatly appreciated!

```
function reportParks(p) {
  document.querySelector(".green").addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("-----PARKS REPORT------");

    //density
    p.forEach((el) => el.densityCalc());

    //average age
    const ages = p.map((el) => new Date().getFullYear() - el.yearCreated);
    const [totalAges, avgAge] = avgCalc(ages);
    console.log(
      `Our ${p.length} parks have a total age of ${totalAges} years and an average age of ${avgAge} years.`
    );
    //which park has more than 1000 trees
    p.forEach((el) => {
      if (el.trees > 1000) {
        console.log(`${el.name} has more than 1000 trees.`);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

`I originally left the var pa out here and just had the reportParks(parks);

```
var pa = reportParks(parks);

function reportStreets(s) {
  document.querySelector(".blue").addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(`--------STREETS REPORT--------`);

    //total and average length of streets
    const [tlengths, lavg] = avgCalc(s.map((el) => el.tlength));
    console.log(
      `The length of all the streets are ${tlengths} km.  The average street length is ${lavg} km.`
    );
    //size class of streets
    s.forEach((el) => el.streetSize());
  });
}
```

`I originally left the var st out here and just had reportStreets(streets);

```
var st = reportStreets(streets);

function orange() {
  document.querySelector(".orange").addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(
      `This is the Parks Report`,
      pa,
      `This is the street report`,
      st
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: You need to restructure your code. You have 1) a named function that 2) assigns an event listener that uses 3) an anonymous function. What you want instead is to 1) declare a named function that logs the report 2) assign it to the click event (exactly once, when your program loads) For instance your code doesn't call `orange()` anywhere, and `pa` is undefined because the `reportStreets` function has no return value.

Comment: Here's how to do this properly: https://jsfiddle.net/xvn0c96y/

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have tried to make the fixes, however, I'm not seeing the correct results.  It seems the only way to make it work is to pass parks in the function so everything gets used, but it is logging immediately not after the click. 
document.querySelector(".green").addEventListener("click", reportParks(parks));

Comment: You must pass a function; what you're doing is calling the function and passing its return value. You need `.addEventListener("click", () => { reportParks(parks); })` or, since it's a single statement, the shorter version: `.addEventListener("click", () => reportParks(parks))`

Comment: Thank you soooo much.  That was driving me crazy.